# What does it mean for a residue to be the constant $z=1/2$?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an excerpt from section 1.6 of Bump's book *Automorphic Forms and Representations*. The Eisenstein series for $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb Z)$ is defined by $$E(z,s) = \pi^{-s} \Gamma(s) \frac12 \sum_{\substack{m,n \in \mathbb Z \\ (m,n) \ne (0,0)}} \frac{y^s}{|mz+n|^{2s}} $$ where $z = x+iy$ lies in the upper half plane. This is absolutely convergent if the real part of $s$ is at least $1$.

Theorem 1.6.1 then starts by saying

> $E(z,s)$, originally defined for $\operatorname{re} (s) > 1$, has meromorphic continuation to all $s$; it is analytic except at $s=$ and $s=0$, where it has simple poles. The residue at $s=1$ is the constant function $z = 1/2$. ...

I don't understand what the last sentence quoted means; it seems to have a "type error" to me, so to speak. What does it mean for the residue to be "$z = 1/2$"? I wonder if this should actually read something like $z \mapsto \frac12$ instead, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "the constant function $z = 1/2$". It should be "the constant function $1/2$".

The function $E(z, s)$ is a two-variable function. For any fixed $z$, it is a meromorphic function in $s$, and its residue at $s = 1$ is $1/2$, regardless of $z$.

In other words, the function $z \mapsto \operatorname{Res}_{s = 1}E(z, s)$ is the constant function $1/2$.

I think the proof should make this clear.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it was a typo in the book, but given how clueless I am, I wanted to double check.